# Find overlapping keywords in a sentence using re/regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re, findall

```
import re
keyword_pattern='love|love India'
Sentence=I love India
Match=re.finditer(pattern, sentence)
```

Example
Keywords=['love', 'love India', 'pakistan']
Sentence= 'I love India'

Output I need: ['love', 'love India']

Output I am getting: [love]

Comment: You should preprocess your keywords so that the program recognizes that "love India" implies "love". Additionally order the keywords in the pattern by descending length to match "love India" instead of "love".

Comment: If you can install PyPi `regex` module, then you can [try a code like this](https://tio.run/##XY/BCsIwDIbve4rc2mLZxfPwvLs3ESk2al1NS1qnA999ds6BeEoC@f4viUO@BFqPo7vFwBkYz/isqg6HR2CboIGd8KFHoeFToSXrzDRF07mUDYn9sn2IJmdkKpCQG1ZSwArES9TX4EimEo9WLskaStd4JF2cPXLCZst3VGpilKgiO8ryL1lVCSkjHXFytPBz0ReYH6hPjqzx/p/XsPAaCsrexIh2FoMaxzc). Basically, `import regex` and then `keyword_pattern = '(?r)(' + '|'.join(sorted(keywords, key=len, reverse=True)) + ')'` and then `regex.findall(keyword_pattern, sentence, overlapped=True)`

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score -2):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) state that

> `re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Return an iterator yielding match objects over **all non-overlapping** matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result.

For the sake of convenience, we can also use `re.findall`, which basically does the same as `[el.group() for el in re.finditer(...)]`, but has the same problem:

> `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Return all **non-overlapping** matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings or tuples. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result.

But since your have nicely separated groups of patterns, just loop over them:

```py
import re

patterns = ["love", "love India"]
sentence = "I love India"

matches = []
for pat in patterns:
    matches += re.findall(pat, sentence)
```

yields for `matches`:

> ['love', 'love India']